# Different font for small caps in Descriptionitem Label

Tags: fonts, formatting, lists

For my Bachelorthesis I defined a new kind of item to use it with the `description` environment.

```
\newcommand{\tfactor}[5][Event]{%
    \item[\textsc{Faktor -- #1 -- #2 }]\hfill\textbf{#3} \\%
    \textbf{\textsc{Text: }}#4\\%
    \textbf{\textsc{Anmerkung: }}#5%
}
```

What I expected was an Item with the same `textsc` font. What I've got looked like this:

[image]

There is clearly a difference in the font.

I figured out that using the `\libertine{}` command fixes it this way

```
\newcommand{\tfactor}[5][Event]{%
    \item[\libertine{\textsc{Faktor -- #1 -- #2 }}]\hfill\textbf{#3} \\%
    \textbf{\textsc{Text: }}#4\\%
    \textsc{\textbf{Anmerkung: }}#5%
}
```

However I would like to fix it the other way round. »Text« and »Anmerkung« should have the same font as »Faktor - Event - ID«

I am still using the `enumitem` package, but don't have any idea how to find out which font this is.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,%Schriftgröße
a4paper,%Papierformat
titlepage
]%Titelseite nicht nummeriert
{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}



\newenvironment{factorlist}
{%
    \begin{description}[nosep,itemsep=5pt,leftmargin=0pt]%
    }
    {%
    \end{description}%
}

\newcommand{\tfactor}[5][Event]{%
    \item[\textsc{Faktor -- #1 -- #2 }]\hfill\textbf{#3} \\%
    \textbf{\textsc{Text: }}#4\\%
    \textsc{\textbf{Anmerkung: }}#5%
}       

\begin{document}
    \begin{factorlist}
        \tfactor{0}{16:24:24.24}{11 Personen sterben 64 werden verletzt}
{Im nahen Umkreis der Absturzstelle befinden sich die Zuschauertribünen} 
    \end{factorlist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please augment your code snippets to create an MWE (minimum working example). As the code snippets don't reveal which fonts you're using (let alone how they are chosen), it's very difficult to tell at the moment what may be going on.

Answer (score 3):

You should be aware of the fact that `scrreprt` typesets description labels in a sans serif font.

```
\documentclass[
   12pt,%Schriftgröße
   a4paper,%Papierformat
   titlepage,%Titelseite nicht nummeriert
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}



\newenvironment{factorlist}
  {\begin{description}[nosep,itemsep=5pt,leftmargin=0pt,font=\normalfont\bfseries]}
  {\end{description}}

\newcommand{\tfactor}[5][Event]{%
    \item[Faktor -- #1 -- #2 ]\hfill\textbf{#3} \\%
    \textbf{Text:} #4\\%
    \textbf{Anmerkung:} #5%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Thing] is a noun;
\item[Happy] is an adjective.
\end{description}

\begin{factorlist}
\tfactor{0}{16:24:24.24}{11 Personen sterben 64 werden verletzt}
  {Im nahen Umkreis der Absturzstelle befinden sich die Zuschauertribünen} 
\end{factorlist}
\end{document}
```

I have removed the small caps, because it's really too much: either boldface or small caps. Reinsert `\scshape` where appropriate, if you *really* want it.

[image]

You may want to use the features of `enumitem` for setting a serif font for all description labels.

Comment: actually I wanted it the other way round. And looking at it, I agree with you smallcaps and boldface together is a bit to much